# Android Animação esconder e revelar texto

Tags: android

Boa tarde galera sou dev android basico,eu preciso que o nome do aplicativo que aparece na minha splash,fique aparecendo e sumindo como acontece no splash inicial do facebook,tipo vai rodar uns 7 segundos,nesse intervalo preciso que o nome do app fique animado pra não parecer que a tela ta parada,obrigado a todos

Comment: galera só pra complementar eu quero que o texto fique piscando bem suave,acho que agora consegui explicar

Comment: Complemente editando sua pergunta.. Lembre-se que iremos ajudar a responder dúvidas e não fazer o trabalho pra você. O que já tentou fazer?

Comment: Coloque uma amostra do seu código que podemos ajudar melhor

Comment: Já olhou aqui? https://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html

Comment: Seria legal tu colocar o código que tem agora, para nao ficar algo do tipo "façam tal coisa para mim".

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a classe abstrata [`Animation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) para realizar a animação, e a classe `AlphaAnimation` para dar suavidade na transição. Depois basta usar o método `setRepeatMode()` como `REVERSE` e o método `setRepeatCount()` passando `INFINITE` para que repita essa animação até você sair da tela. Veja:

#### Programaticamente:

```
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
// definição do tempo de duração da animação
animation.setDuration(500); 
animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

// aqui você coloca seu TextView ou ImageView, ou
// até mesmo outra view, da forma como você quiser
findViewById(R.id.textView).startAnimation(animation);
```

#### Usando XML:

Ou também, pode criar um XML dentro do diretório `anim`

*`res/anim/fadeinout.xml`*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="500"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    />
```

Na sua *main*, você usa o método `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation()` desta forma:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.fadeinout);
findViewById(R.id.textView).startAnimation(animation);
```

Desta forma como descrevi acima, dará efeito ao `TextView`. Caso você opte por um `ImageView`, usando o mesmo código, o resultado será este abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### ...*uns 7 segundos*

Como você comentou: "*tipo vai rodar uns 7 segundos*", basta você usar o `Handler()`. Veja:

```
// a animação deve estar fora do Handler.
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       // aqui dentro você insere o código para sair dessa tela
    }
}, 7000); // 7000 milesegundos equivale a 7 segundos.
```